# Equality of bivariate formal series

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Is it possible to prove algebraically that the two series uniquely defined by the following equations are equal:
$L_1=uz+zL_1^2+z \partial_uL_1$ and
$L_2=uz+z^2+z L_2^2+2z^4 \partial_zL_2$

Comment: Induction? What induction?

Comment: @abx There is a unique formal power series in $(u,z)$ satisfied by each recurrence. They can be found by starting with 0 and repeatedly applying the recurrence; probably that's what OP means by "induction".  I checked it up to total degree 30.

Comment: @Brendan McKay: Oh, I see, thanks. Thus the question, though poorly formulated, makes sense.

Comment: Use techniques from differential algebra to prove the equality

Comment: Why is this question being phrased as an order, and why must one use a specific method?

Comment: Sorry English is not my native language, I correct the sentence.

Comment: Using symbolic method, the equality is easy to prove, I would like to know if someone could prove it without combinatorial interpretation…

Comment: My reading of your paper referenced in [OEIS A062980](https://oeis.org/A062980) is that you already know that the solution is $$L(u,z) = \frac{1 - \sqrt{1-4uz^2}}{2z} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} A062980(k) \left( \frac{z}{\sqrt{1 - 4uz^2}} \right)^{3k+2}$$ Is differentiating this and showing that it satisfies both of your identities "too combinatorial"?

Comment: The two equations seem really simple and I would like to know if only by a differential algebra type approach it is possible to obtain the equality. For example by embedding the series in an algebraic structure (more complicated than a vector space) which would ensure that if the two series coincide at a finite number of points then they are identical.